# How to check parameter value existence in a procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql

The following is a procedure that uses 2 parameters: `customer_code` and `pay_amount`. The procedure works as expected, however when I enter wrong `cus_code` I get this error instead of my custom checking:

```
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "XXXXX.CUST_PAY", line 19
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

The procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE cust_pay (temp_ccode IN NUMBER, pay_amount IN NUMBER)AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE 
      Value_check NUMBER;
      cbalance NUMBER;
    BEGIN
        SELECT Count(cus_code) 
        INTO value_check
        FROM customer
        WHERE cus_code = temp_ccode;

        IF value_check IS NULL THEN
            Dbms_Output.put_line('the value was not FOUND');
        ELSE
            UPDATE customer
            SET cus_balance = cus_balance - pay_amount
            WHERE cus_code = temp_ccode;

            SELECT cus_balance 
            INTO cbalance
            FROM customer
            WHERE cus_code = temp_ccode;

            IF cbalance < 0 THEN
                Dbms_Output.put_line('The client owes us ' || cbalance);
            ELSE
                Dbms_Output.put_line('Customer new balance is ' || cbalance);
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END;
END;
```

What did I do wrong? I guess I need to check the value before I `SELECT`, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use a `count()` aggregate on a resultset that has no rows, you'll get zero, not a null.

If a `SELECT` doesn't find anything, an exception is raised (`NO_DATA_FOUND`), and you need to catch that exception in an `EXCEPTIONS` block.

```
exceptions
  when no_data_found:
    dbms_output.put_line('ooups');
end;
```

In your case the second select is raising the exception - since zero is not null, your first `if` branch will not be taken. (`update` doesn't raise an exception if it doesn't update anything.)

Your procedure is generally too complicate already though. You can declare variables in the procedure "header" directly, remove both selects - all the info you want can be gotten from a single `update`.

```
create or replace
procedure cust_pay(temp_code number, pay_amount number)
as
  new_balance number;
begin
  update customer
  set cbalance = cbalance - pay_amount
  where cust_code = temp_code
  returning cbalance into new_balance;

  if sql%rowcount = 0 then
    dbms_output.put_line('No such customer: ' || temp_code);
  elsif new_balance < 0 then
    dbms_output.put_line('Negative: ' || new_balance);
  else
    dbms_output.put_line('Positive: ' || new_balance);
  end if;
end;
```

(This assumes that `cust_code` is unique.)

If the update didn't do anything, `sql%rowcount` will be zero, which tells you whether that customer exists or not (equivalent to your first `select`).
The update itself is unchanged from your code except that the `returning ... into` avoids the need for your third select and grabs the updated value directly into a local variable.